# Play frame work 2.2 No of parallel threads configuration

Tags: playframework-2.2

Hi we are using play frame work 2.2. We are doing concurrent execution by using Promise.promise. But as of now its spawning a batch of 8 threads.Once this 8 thread over it will move to next 8 threads. But we need to run more than this concurrently. How can we configure this parallelism in our configuration. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for the above, please put the below piece of code in application.conf file. You can adjust with  parallelism-max and parallelism-min values.
play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 500
          parallelism-min = 500
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: For the record there is some pretty detailed docs about it in the play documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools